# My ajax button loading state only fires after the request is complete when posting a form with image upload and other inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Not sure what is happening, but I have this form that has a file input and other input elements. When I submit the form via ajax, everything works fine except for the fact that my button loading state does not fire before performing the ajax request. I am left with a situation where the user may not notice that a request is already in progress, and become tempted to click and click again.

Here is my code
The HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" class="riderOnboardForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputBName" class="h6">Dispatch name *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputBName" name="inputBName" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCNumber" class="h6">Contact number *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputCNumber" name="inputCNumber" required>                                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputSLocation" class="h6">Select location *</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="inputSLocation" name="inputSLocation" required>
                    <option value="">Select location</option>
                    <option value="1">Locations list</option>
                </select>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputMinCharge" class="h6">Minimum Charge</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputMinCharge" name="inputMinCharge">                                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputDDays" class="h6 d-block mb-2">I work on</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Mon" checked class="pt-1" id="inputDDays1">
                <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays1">Mon</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Tue" checked class="" id="inputDDays2">
                <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays2">Tue</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Wed" checked class="" id="inputDDays3">
                <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays3">Wed</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Thu" checked class="" id="inputDDays4">
                <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays4">Thu</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Fri" checked class="" id="inputDDays5">
                <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays5">Fri</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Sat" checked class="" id="inputDDays6">
                <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays6">Sat</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Sun" checked class="" id="inputDDays7">
                <label class="mr-2 h6" for="inputDDays7">Sun</label>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputWFrom" class="h6">I work from</label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <select class="form-control " id="inputWFrom" name="inputWFrom">
                            <option value="">work time</option>   
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 text-center pt-2">
                        <span class="h6">to</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <select class="form-control " id="inputWTo" name="inputWTo">
                            <option value="">work time</option>  
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>                            
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputLUpload" class="h6">Logo file</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inputLUpload" name="inputLUpload">
                <small class="form-text text-agito-yellow">Accepted formats: 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png' less than 5mb</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-agito-yellow  hvr-bob p-2" id="btnOnboardRider"><h3 class="font-weight-bolder pt-2">Enrol TODAY</h3></button>                        
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
var request;
$("body").on("submit", ".riderOnboardForm", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
//the next 3 lines actually fire, but the button state does not change. It is almost as if it pauses, runs the ajax first before it enters the loading state
        var btnTxt = "btnOnboardRider";
        var btnHtml = $("#" + btnTxt).html();
        buttonLoad("Please wait... Upload and saving in progress", btnTxt, false);//this calls and external function

        // Abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var $form = $(this);    

        var formData = new FormData($form[0]);
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        // Fire off the request
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "some-server-side-script",
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response) {
                var responseObj = $.parseJSON(response);
                if (parseInt(responseObj.status) < 0) {
                    if (responseObj.status == -1) {
                        $.notify(responseObj.msg, {position: "bottom right", className: 'error'});
                    } else {
                        $('#modalFeedback').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                            var modal = $(this);
                            modal.find('.modal-body').html(responseObj.msg)
                        });
                        $('#modalFeedback').modal('show');
                    }
                } else {
                    $('#modalFeedback').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                        var modal = $(this);
                        modal.find('.modal-body').html(responseObj.msg);
                    });
                    $('#modalFeedback').modal('show');
                    $form.find("input, select, file, textarea").val("");
                }
            } else {
                noResponseMessage();
            }
        });
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {           
            displayNoConnectionError(textStatus, errorThrown);
        });
        request.always(function () {
            buttonUnload(btnHtml, btnTxt, false);
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });
    });
```

Functions

```
function noResponseMessage() {
        $.notify("No response from server. Please try again later.", {position: "bottom right", className: 'warn'});
    }

    function displayNoConnectionError(textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.notify("Please check connection. An error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown, {position: "bottom right", className: 'error'});
    }


    function buttonLoad(loadtxt, handle, isClass) {
        var this_ref = $("#" + handle);
        if (isClass) {
            this_ref = $("." + handle);
        }
        var markup = '<span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> ' + loadtxt;
        this_ref.html(markup);
        this_ref.attr("disabled", true);
    }

    function buttonUnload(loadtxt, handle, isClass) {
        var this_ref = $("#" + handle);
        if (isClass) {
            this_ref = $("." + handle);
        }
        this_ref.html(loadtxt);
        this_ref.attr("disabled", false);
    }
```

I'll appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: can you include the buttonLoad() function?

Comment: Sure. I edited the question by adding logic for all self defined functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **UPDATE:**

### **To make the submission more aesthetically pleasing and responsive:**

I added a *setTimeout(function())*  around the entire ajax request. this gives js a small break allowing it to update the button and from fields before it starts doing the heavy lifting. I also added variables at the top of the code for the timers so its easier to tweak.

```
//timeOut timers
var ajaxTimer = 500; //time that js will wait before it attempts the ajax call (milliseconds) 
var formDelay = 1000; //time that js will wait before it re-enables the form inputs and button
```

For the full code of the timeOut ajax request check the snippet. I have cut it down here to reduce the size of this post.

```
   ...
     var btnTxt = "btnOnboardRider";
     var btnHtml = $("#" + btnTxt).html();
     buttonLoad("Please wait... Upload and saving in progress", btnTxt, false);//this calls and external function
   ...

 setTimeout(function(){ //warp the heavy ajax and form data in a timeout function
     
     var formData = new FormData($form[0]);   
     
     // Fire off the request
      request = $.ajax({
          url: "some-server-side-script",
          type: "post",
          async: false,
          data: formData,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          beforeSend: function(){
             buttonLoad("Please wait... Upload and saving in progress", btnTxt, false);//this calls and external function
          }

      });
      request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          if (response) {
              var responseObj = $.parseJSON(response);
              if (parseInt(responseObj.status) < 0) {
                  if (responseObj.status == -1) {
                      $.notify(responseObj.msg, {position: "bottom right", className: 'error'});
                  } else {
                      $('#modalFeedback').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                          var modal = $(this);
                          modal.find('.modal-body').html(responseObj.msg)
                      });
                      $('#modalFeedback').modal('show');
                  }
              } else {
                  $('#modalFeedback').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                      var modal = $(this);
                      modal.find('.modal-body').html(responseObj.msg);
                  });
                  $('#modalFeedback').modal('show');
                  $form.find("input, select, file, textarea").val("");
              }
          } else {
              noResponseMessage();
          }
      });
      request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {           
          displayNoConnectionError(textStatus, errorThrown);
      });
       request.always(function () {
       //put code in time out
          setTimeout(function(){ 
              //unlock the form by setting isProcessing = false
              isProcessing = false;
              buttonUnload(btnHtml, btnTxt, false);
              $inputs.prop("disabled", false);

            }, formDelay); //defined above
      });
      
     }, ajaxTimer); //defined above, end of ajax and form data timeout function
```

### **To prevent the techincal issue of the from being submitted twice by a quick clicker:**

I updated the code snippet to include a var which locks the submission process if it is true.

Heres the declaration:

```
var isProcessing = false;
```

...

Then, inside the submit event handler we need to check if its being processed and if it is break out by returing true else set the processing var to true and continue to submit the form as per usual:

```
  if(isProcessing){ //if the form is currently being processed
      // return true, this will prevent the form from being submitted twice
      return isProcessing;
    }else{
      // lock the form by setting  isProcessing = true
      isProcessing = true;
    }
```

Then, in the request.always() function we set the isProcessing var to false to unlock the form submission.

```
 request.always(function () {
     //put code in time out
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            //unlock the form by setting isProcessing = false
            isProcessing = false;
            buttonUnload(btnHtml, btnTxt, false);
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
             
          }, 1000); //1 second
    });
```

This should prevent the ajax request from happening twice as it will only get submitted if isProcessing = false.

### Additional things we tried:

*We tried to make the button disable before the ajax request using 'beforeSend'. We also added a delay so that if the request was completing too quickly we could see some feedback. See Below:*

In the ajax request I added the beforeSend function and moved the call to buttonLoad() inside it:

```
request = $.ajax({
            url: "some-server-side-script",
            type: "post",
            async: false,
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
               buttonLoad("Please wait... Upload and saving in progress", btnTxt, false);//this calls and external function
            }
           
        });
```

and I changed the request always function to have a delay:

```
   request.always(function () {
     //put code in time out
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            //unlock the form by setting isProcessing = false
            isProcessing = false;
            buttonUnload(btnHtml, btnTxt, false);
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);

          }, 1000); //1 second
    });
```

### Here is the complete code in action:

```js
var request;
var isProcessing = false; //for locking the form submission

//timeOut timers
var ajaxTimer = 500; //time that js will wait before it attempts the ajax call (milliseconds) 
var formDelay = 1000; //time that js will wait before it re-enables the form inputs and button

$("body").on("submit", ".riderOnboardForm", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        
        if(isProcessing){ //if the form is currently being processed
          // return true, this will prevent the form from being submitted twice
          return isProcessing;
        }else{
          // lock the form by setting  isProcessing = true
          isProcessing = true;
        }
        
//the next 3 lines actually fire, but the button state does not change. It is almost as if it pauses, runs the ajax first before it enters the loading state
        var btnTxt = "btnOnboardRider";
        var btnHtml = $("#" + btnTxt).html();
       buttonLoad("Please wait... Upload and saving in progress", btnTxt, false);//this calls and external function

        // Abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }

        var $form = $(this);    
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
        
        setTimeout(function(){ //warp the heavy ajax and form data in a timeout function
         
         var formData = new FormData($form[0]);   
         
         // Fire off the request
          request = $.ajax({
              url: "some-server-side-script",
              type: "post",
              async: false,
              data: formData,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              beforeSend: function(){
                 buttonLoad("Please wait... Upload and saving in progress", btnTxt, false);//this calls and external function
              }

          });
          request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              if (response) {
                  var responseObj = $.parseJSON(response);
                  if (parseInt(responseObj.status) < 0) {
                      if (responseObj.status == -1) {
                          $.notify(responseObj.msg, {position: "bottom right", className: 'error'});
                      } else {
                          $('#modalFeedback').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                              var modal = $(this);
                              modal.find('.modal-body').html(responseObj.msg)
                          });
                          $('#modalFeedback').modal('show');
                      }
                  } else {
                      $('#modalFeedback').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                          var modal = $(this);
                          modal.find('.modal-body').html(responseObj.msg);
                      });
                      $('#modalFeedback').modal('show');
                      $form.find("input, select, file, textarea").val("");
                  }
              } else {
                  noResponseMessage();
              }
          });
          request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {           
              displayNoConnectionError(textStatus, errorThrown);
          });
           request.always(function () {
           //put code in time out
              setTimeout(function(){ 
                  //unlock the form by setting isProcessing = false
                  isProcessing = false;
                  buttonUnload(btnHtml, btnTxt, false);
                  $inputs.prop("disabled", false);

                }, formDelay); //defined above
          });
          
         }, ajaxTimer); //defined above, end of ajax and form data timeout function
    });

function noResponseMessage() {
        $.notify("No response from server. Please try again later.", {position: "bottom right", className: 'warn'});
    }

    function displayNoConnectionError(textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.notify("Please check connection. An error occurred: " + textStatus, errorThrown, {position: "bottom right", className: 'error'});
    }


    function buttonLoad(loadtxt, handle, isClass) {
        var this_ref = $("#" + handle);
        if (isClass) {
            this_ref = $("." + handle);
        }
        var markup = '<span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> ' + loadtxt;
        this_ref.html(markup);
        this_ref.attr("disabled", true);
    }

    function buttonUnload(loadtxt, handle, isClass) {
        var this_ref = $("#" + handle);
        if (isClass) {
            this_ref = $("." + handle);
        }
        this_ref.html(loadtxt);
        this_ref.attr("disabled", false);
    }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-notify@3.1.3/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST" class="riderOnboardForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputBName" class="h6">Dispatch name *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputBName" name="inputBName" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputCNumber" class="h6">Contact number *</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputCNumber" name="inputCNumber" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputSLocation" class="h6">Select location *</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="inputSLocation" name="inputSLocation" required>
          <option value="">Select location</option>
          <option value="1">Locations list</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputMinCharge" class="h6">Minimum Charge</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputMinCharge" name="inputMinCharge">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputDDays" class="h6 d-block mb-2">I work on</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Mon" checked class="pt-1" id="inputDDays1">
        <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays1">Mon</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Tue" checked class="" id="inputDDays2">
        <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays2">Tue</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Wed" checked class="" id="inputDDays3">
        <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays3">Wed</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Thu" checked class="" id="inputDDays4">
        <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays4">Thu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Fri" checked class="" id="inputDDays5">
        <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays5">Fri</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Sat" checked class="" id="inputDDays6">
        <label class="mr-3 h6" for="inputDDays6">Sat</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="inputDDays[]" value="Sun" checked class="" id="inputDDays7">
        <label class="mr-2 h6" for="inputDDays7">Sun</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputWFrom" class="h6">I work from</label>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-5">
            <select class="form-control " id="inputWFrom" name="inputWFrom">
              <option value="">work time</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 text-center pt-2">
            <span class="h6">to</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">
            <select class="form-control " id="inputWTo" name="inputWTo">
              <option value="">work time</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputLUpload" class="h6">Logo file</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inputLUpload" name="inputLUpload">
        <small class="form-text text-agito-yellow">Accepted formats: 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png' less than 5mb</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-agito-yellow  hvr-bob p-2" id="btnOnboardRider"><h3 class="font-weight-bolder pt-2">Enrol TODAY</h3></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Still does not fire the button load status before sending the request. It's almost as if it freezes everything before sending the request. The funny thinh is that it works without the ```var formData = new FormData($form[0]);``` logic, but I need that to submit the file plus other user inputs. Does this have anything to do with new FormData()?

Comment: there is a function that executes code before an Ajax request is sent. I'll update my answer to show.

Comment: I updated the answer to use beforeSend. this will make the code trigger before it sends the AJAX request. IF it still looks like its not working try increase the delay in the timeout function. When I run the snippet it seems to work as expected.

Comment: I tried the update code. No luck. It's crazy. Here is a link to my recorded screen to show you how exactly it behaves - https://clipchamp.com/watch/NhizMgO6iLe. Notice when I click "Enrol TODAY", I get feedback from the server before the loading state even kicks in. I am actually able to see the loading now because of the 1 second wait time.  Usually, it just goes and comes back. This is localhost, so it's faster. On live server, there is  a longer pause with nothing happening, and users will be tempted to click again, thereby aborting the previous request and sending a new one.

Comment: I updated the answer, this time I am using a variable to prevent the form from being submitted more than onnce. I hope that nails it XD.

Comment: By observation, this looks to me like a way to manage multiple requests. But taking aesthetics into consideration, I'll really love the loading state to trigger on click. There is a feeling attached to it and great UI/UX experience. :) Well, I have not tried the update yet, but I'll certainly let you know how it goes as soon as I do.

Comment: I think you are right about that. I have one more thing to try. I think the delay is in relation to the form data as you mentioned in a previous comment. I noticed if I attach an image it takes longer to change state of the button. maybe it's taking time to load the file into the browser memory? we could try add a delay around the form data and Ajax request to let JS change the state of the button.

Comment: I like the direction you're going. I have strong reason to think the form data has something to do with this. If we can tweak something on that just like you suggest, I think we'll get it right. Unfortunately, I'm out of ideas for now.

Comment: I'll update my answer later today. there are a few things left we can do.

Comment: Updated the answer, give that a go. let me know how you go.

Comment: Hey, It worked! Thanks, @RyDog. We got the fancy button to change the state right after it is clicked. The formData was the headache. I stripped a few extra things that were not really needed in my context, but the setTimeout wrap around the whole ajax thing including the formData did the trick. I am really grateful. Can you believe this is my first question on StackOverflow since I joined 3 days ago? :) If there is anything I can do as a recommendation when you get what you need on StackOverflow, I am happy to learn.

Comment: great to hear. was good challenge. yeah the answer became a bit flabby. but we got there! you don't need to do anything else as you have already accepted this as the answer. thanks!